# Can we convert a .msg to jpeg using imagemagick?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I need to convert a .msg file to an jpeg image. Can we do it using ImageMagick ?

I tried to run the below command,

```
  magick mail.msg mail.jpeg
```

but it gives an error :

```
 magick: no decode delegate for this image format `MSG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/512.
```

I need .msg to be converted into an image.

Can you please suggest if that is possible.

Thanks,
Abha

Comment: .msg isn't an image format, as far as I can tell. What sort of output do you expect?

Comment: What is an `msg` file, please? Which application creates such a thing? Please provide one.

Comment: If that MSG file is just text, you can try to coax ImageMagick into recognizing and reading it as a text file if you add a format prefix to the filename in your command. In this case that would look like this... "TEXT:mail.msg".

Comment: As GeeMack suggested, if it is simple text, then try `magick "TEXT:mail.msg" mail.jpg`. Otherwise, provide an example of the msg format file.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Outlook mail creates a message with this format.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your replies. .MSG is actually a outlook mail. I want to store the text from an outlook mail as an image. I tried with magick "TEXT:mail.msg" mail.jpg , but this gives a 5 images which are not in readable format.